# how to access function values in js

Tags: javascript

I have a js function where I am trying to implementing binary tree. I have one function which create a node ,it's left and it's right child, like so

```
bst.prototype.cNode = function (x_) {
    this.node = x_;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
};

var a = new bst(); 
a.cNode(5);
```

This gives me first node and it's left and right.

Next I am trying to push left/right child check with the current node value whether is greater than node or lesser that node like so

```
a.pushChild(2);


//
function bst(){

    this.pushChild = function(w_){

        if(w_ < this.node){
            if(this.left == null){
                this.left = new this.cNode(w_);
            }
            else{
                this.pushChild(w_);
            }
        }
        else if(w_ > this.node){
            if(this.right == null){
                this.right = new this.cNode(w_);
            }
            else{

            }
        }

    }


}
```

It is giving me Maximun stack error because it is struck in infinite loop because it is always checking with the first this.node and this.left and this.right but this.left and this.right also has this.node,ths.left,this.right also i want to check with that not with the first one always.

How can is check with the latest values and not with the first node,left,right values?

Answer (score 0):

You are repeatedly calling the function on the first node, instead call it on the left or right node, as required:

```
this.pushChild = function(w_){

    if(w_ < this.node){
        if(this.left == null){
            this.left = new this.cNode(w_);
        }
        else{
            this.left.pushChild(w_);
        }
    }
    else if(w_ > this.node){
        if(this.right == null){
            this.right = new this.cNode(w_);
        }
        else{
            this.right.pushChild(w_);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is not the actual solution but this idea helped me solve this. Thanks :)

Comment: i have to push the whole function inside the left/right child in order to gain access the pushChild funtion.

Comment: maybe it's better if you post the actual solution yourself and accept it, so it can help others :)